# overflow in bootstrap 4 behaves wonky

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, scrollbar

I have a div inside a modal where a lot of checkboxes get added dynamically. the div is a class="col-6" (based on the default grid classes for bootstrap 4) and I added the class "scroll" to have a scroll bar. I set it with overflow-y: auto; and I hid the overflow-x. It looks like this:

[image]

When there are a lot of checkboxes inside the div, it works fine. But when I only have 5 checkboxes, the bar appears. It shouldn't though, since the height of the modal should be sufficient...and the funny thing is, that when you click the last checkbox, the scroll bar suddenly dissapears!

[image]

Any Idea of why is this happening and how to fix it? i'll appreciate a lot your help!

Comment: what if you don't mention overflow-y at all?

Comment: I don't think you can add a scrollbar to a div if you don't define the overflows.... how will the scroll be visible if I dont define the overflows?

`.scroll{
     height: auto;
     max-height: 550px;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
}`